# Can C compiler prefetch data around the call?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization, prefetch

Is it possible to good C compiler with high optimization enabled to optimize code with prefetches and to place prefetches before some function call:

```
struct *abc;
//...

function_first(&(abc->field1));
abc->field2= abc->field3+ abc->field4 + abc->field5 + ...; 
// a lot work on struct fields
function_second(&(abc->field1))
```

So, can code after compiler optimization to have a prefetches for `abc` fields and move it higher than `function_first()` call, like this:

```
struct *abc;
//...

__prefetch(abc->field2);__prefetch(abc->field5);
function_first(&(abc->field1));
abc->field2= abc->field3+ abc->field4 + abc->field5 + ...; 
// a lot work on struct fields
function_second(&(abc->field1))
```

The function `function_first()` can be annotated as `clean` (have no side-effects on abc fields other than field1), or the programm can be compiled in whole-program optimization (-ipo  /Qipo for intel), where compiler can check, what `function_first` do.

UPDATE: without calls the prefetches are possible, but this question is about mixing calls and prefetches

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Intel's ICC compiler can do this (*). It's debatable whether it actually makes any difference to performance though.

(*) See the [-opt-prefetch=n](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011/compiler_c/copts/common_options/option_opt_prefetch.htm) switch.

Comment: Paul, can Intel move prefetch before the call?

Comment: You'd have to try it and see. Prefetch tends to be of limited use though, except for a very small subset of cases.

Comment: this question is about moving prefetches before calls. at the moment I have no Intel compiler installed, so I can't try it.

Comment: if you're really worried about it you could use an explicit prefetch intrinsic...

Comment: @osgx: you can get a free 30 day evaluation licence for ICC from intel.com so it's not difficult to install it and try it out